# Using a 'mousemove' event in Meteor

Tags: meteor, mousemove

I want to use a 'mousemove' event in Meteor, I know how it's done in usual JavaScript but can't figure out how to implement it in Meteor.

I have this code already in meteor:

```
  Template.index.events({
    'mousemove': function(e){
        var mouseX = e.pagex - $('#index').offset().left;
        var totalX = $('#index').width();
        var centerX =totalX / 2;
        var shiftX = centerX - mouseX;
        var startX = ($('#index').width() / 2) -($ ('image').width() / 2);

        $('image1').css('z-index');
        $('image1').css({'left': startX + (shiftX/10) + 'px'});
        console.log('mouse move');
    }
});
```

It does register the mousemove event but doesn't move the image

What it supposed to do:
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5f1ksvs0/)

How would I implement such an event in Meteor?

Comment: Please do not edit your question in such a drastic way, it is confusing and leads to off-topic answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meteor affords you some built in [eventmaps](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps). Per the documentation, you get access to click, doubleclick, mousedown, mouseup, mouseenter, mouseleave, and a few others.

It doesn't specifically say that mousemove is included, so it might not work in all browsers. I've tested in chrome and it does.

You would do so like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
  'mousemove': function(){
   //dostuffhere
  }
});
```

If you wanted to implement a mousemove (or any other event that doesn't have an eventMap) - you can do so maybe in a template's rendered function like so.

```
Template.mytemplate.rendered = function(){
    $('#index').on('mousemove', function(){
         //dostuffhere
    })
}
```